# Shopify - hidden properties['...'] in /cart/add form are visible in shopping cart

Tags: shopify, product, cart

Inside `<form action="/cart/add">` I am using

```
<input type="hidden" name="properties[myId]" />
```

to add some technical ID's to the product which I then read using a hook when the product is purchased. It is all working fine except that my hidden inputs are visible in the cart (and it doesn't look very good). Is there a way to add properties which do not appear in the product description in the shopping cart but are still part of the item properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Placing an underscore at the beginning of the name hides the property: `<input type="hidden" name="properties[_myId]" />`

https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/products/get-customization-information-for-products#hide-line-item-properties

Note: while this is true for most themes I have seen some themes where this is not respected... to be used with caution.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea that was possible! Thanks Francois!

Answer (score 1):

Add them to cart attributes. Use `attributes[myId]` instead of `properties[myId]`

More details - [Get more information on your cart page with cart attributes](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/cart/get-more-information-with-cart-attributes)

Comment: Or you can edit cart.liquid to hide those specific properties

Comment: Thanks @Hymnz but attributes are at the cart level (whereas properties are at the item level).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This answer is wrong. As [Francois' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38414017/4302668) has shown, it is possible to have hidden properties without making the merchant edit their liquid code.

---

If you look at your "cart.liquid", there should be some code in there like this:

```
{% for p in item.properties %}
   ...
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to store some information in a line item's properties without it being visible on the cart page, you need to edit the liquid code to keep it from being output. One way to do this is to remember the names of the properties that need to be hidden, and stop them from being output with an if or unless:

```
{% for p in item.properties %}
   {% unless p.first == 'hidden_prop_1' or p.first == 'hidden_prop_2' %}
     ...
   {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```